# How to reuse entities, DTOs and client service interfaces from a GWT app to another

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, cordova

We are developing an appliation (client+server) using GWT and hosted in GAE. Now we want to implement a mobile app (GWT + phonegap) that will connect to the server part of the application. I would like to use the same entities, DTOs and client service interfaces in the client that we used in the web page.

Is that possible? If I execute a RPC with the phonegap page as a webpage I get a 0 error (I suppose it is about crossdomain issues), but if I execute in the android emulator I get a "Failed to get the SerializationPolicy" exception.

I want to know if I can do what I want and work with both the page as page for debugging and in the emulator.

If this is very difficult, how could I reuse the old code? or... which is the best way to go in my situation (gwt app (client+server) with a mobile phonegap page connected to the same server in GAE)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog entry on how to use GWT RPC and phonegap together: http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/04/gwt-rpc-with-phonegap-revisited.html

Answer (score 1):

What you might want to do is to use request factory instead of the rpc service mechanism which does not required serializable objects. This also has a native java jar that can be used inside android environment.

Here is an excellent video for using ClientFactory go implement device type gwt ui's
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1aCo5LvMf8

Here is another video that was helpful for me that explains using the same request factory code for native android java and for gwt
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U

Comment: that way I would need to rebuild my app, or duplicate the code :S